# compare two arrays of objects and sort based on one array of objects and push when doesn't match

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, angular, reactjs

I have two arrays in javascript

```
array1 = [{id: 4, value:'xyz'}, {id: 2, value:'pqr'}, {id: 5, value:'abc'}]
array2 = [
         [{id: 5, value:'abc'}, {id: 4, value:'xyz'}],
         [{id: 5, value:'abc'}, {id: 2, value:'pqr'}],
         [{id: 4, value:'xyz'}, {id: 2, value:'pqr'}],
         [{id: 2, value:'pqr'}, {id: 5, value:'abc'}]
]
```

array2 is array of array of objects,
all these arrays inside array 2 should be first of all sorted as per the array1 sequence and then object with null should be pushed if that particular id doesn't exist at that particular index.

```
output = [
         [{id: 4, value:'xyz'}, {id: null, value:null}, {id: 5, value:'abc'}],
         [{id: null, value:null}, {id: 2, value:'pqr'}, {id: 5, value:'abc'}],
         [{id: 4, value:'xyz'}, {id: 2, value:'pqr'}, {id: null, value:null}],
         [{id: 4, value:'xyz'}, {id: 2, value:'pqr'}, {id: null, value:null}],
         [{id: null, value:null}, {id: 2, value:'pqr'}, {id: 5, value:'abc'}]
].
```

Here is my code

```
export const mapOrder = (array, order, key) => {
    let arr = [];
    array.sort((a, b) => {
        let A = a[key];
        let B = b[key];
        if (order.indexOf(A) > order.indexOf(B)) {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    });
    if (order.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (order[i] === array[j].UserId) {
                    arr.push(array[j]);
                } else {
                    arr.push({ id: null, value: null})
                }
            }
        }
        array = arr;
    }
    return arr;
};
```

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: @NinaScholz I've added the code

Answer (score 0):

First you can loop over the second array and save the ID's to a new Set, Then loop over the first array and if the current item's ID is present in the set then return the current object or return the object with `id` and value as null`

```js
const array1 = [{id: 4, value:'xyz'}, {id: 2, value:'pqr'}, {id: 5, value:'abc'}]
const array2 = [{id: 5, value:'abc'}, {id: 4, value:'xyz'}]

function test(arr1, arr2) {
  const set = new Set()
  arr2.forEach(i => set.add(i.id))
  return arr1.map((i) => set.has(i.id) ? i : { id: null, value: null })
}
console.log(test(array1,array2))
```

Comment: The quadratic complexity can be avoided if you use a Set for `arr2Ids` instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a Map from your array2, where each id from the objects in array2 point to an array of objects with that particular `id` value. Then you can use `.flatMap()` on `array1` and get all the objects for the `id` of the currently iterated object by using `.get()` on your map. If `.get()` returns nothing, you can provide the default object (where id and value are `null`):

```js
const array1 = [{id: 4, value:'xyz'}, {id: 2, value:'pqr'}, {id: 5, value:'abc'}];
const array2 = [{id: 5, value:'abc'}, {id: 4, value:'xyz'}];

// group the arrays into a Map
const grouped = array2.reduce((map, obj) => 
  map.set(obj.id, (map.get(obj.id) || []).concat(obj)),
  new Map
);

const res = array1.flatMap(({id}) => grouped.get(id) || ({id: null, value: null}));
console.log(res);
```

You might be able to remove the `.flatMap()` and the need to array of objects in your `Map` if objects in array2 have unique `id` values (ie: an object with the same idea cannot exist). If this can be the case, you can simplify the above:

```js
const array1 = [{id: 4, value:'xyz'}, {id: 2, value:'pqr'}, {id: 5, value:'abc'}];
const array2 = [{id: 5, value:'abc'}, {id: 4, value:'xyz'}];

const ids = new Map(array2.map((obj) => [obj.id, obj]));
const res = array1.map(({id}) => ids.get(id) || ({id: null, value: null}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the object in an object first and them map the collected objects or take a placeholder.

```js
var array1 = [{ id: 4, value: 'xyz' }, { id: 2, value: 'pqr' }, { id: 5, value: 'abc' }],
    array2 = [{ id: 5, value: 'abc' }, { id: 4, value: 'xyz' }],
    result = array1.map(
        (o => ({ id }) => o[id] || { id: null, value: null })
        (array2.reduce((r, o) => ({ ...r, [o.id]: o }), {}))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```